# Difference between giving dependencies in profile and giving dependencies outside of profile in maven pom.xml

Tags: maven, pom.xml

What is the difference between giving the dependencies in profile and giving normal dependencies.

Below given a pom.xml with dependencies and profile blocks only.

But I dont know what is the difference.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.storm</groupId>
            <artifactId>storm-kafka</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.3</version>
        </dependency>       
    </dependencies>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>one</id>                
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.storm</groupId>
                    <artifactId>storm-core</artifactId>
                    <version>0.9.3</version>                    
                </dependency>               
            </dependencies>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>two</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.storm</groupId>
                    <artifactId>storm-core</artifactId>
                    <version>0.9.3</version>
                    <scope>provided</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>log4j-over-slf4j</artifactId>
                    <version>1.6.6</version>
                    <scope>provided</scope>
                </dependency>               
            </dependencies>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

Answer (score 2):

The dependencies and configuration in a profile are only applied, when the profile is active. In your case, profile one is not active by default, so you would have to activate it when you call Maven. Profile two is always active, because of `<activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>`.
You can activate profiles with the parameter `-P`, e.g. `mvn clean install -Pone`.